Making an HTTPS connection to an endpoint using golang fails while curl and C# code succeeds
Trying to make an https connection using golang. getting the following error always.
"An existing connection was forcibly closed by remote host".
Tried the same endpoint on the same machine  using curl or using HttpClient from C#.net . it is able to make a successful connection. But the golang script fails with the  above error.
Looked at the TCP packets. While using golang server sets the RST bit causing the connection reset.This doesn't happen while using the HttpClient. from C#.Sharing the golang  code here.
url := ""

client := &http.Client{
    Timeout: 5 * time.Second,

    Transport: &http.Transport{
        MaxIdleConns:      10,
        ForceAttemptHTTP2: true,
        TLSNextProto:      make(map[string]func(authority string, c *tls.Conn) http.RoundTripper),
        TLSClientConfig:   &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    },
}


for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    resp, err := client.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error sending request #%d: %v\n", i+1, err)
        continue
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Printf("Request #%d sent, Status Code: %d\n", i+1, resp.StatusCode)
}



You are making a HTTPS (not HTTP).  HTTP TLS is used to establish a secure connection BEFORE the HTTP request is sent.  The connection is failing due to TLS failing.  TLS the server sends a list of certificate names and then the client looks up the names in installed certificate to find a matching name.  Is connection failing between the same two machine or between different machines?  If same machines the certificate is installed properly.  Since Net 4.7.1 TLS is performed in OS and not in Net Library.  I need more info about machines and Net to determine what is wrong.

@jdweng , These are two different machines. In the C# code , i explicitly tried to check if the SAN of cert matches with the host name and it succeeds. As I mentioned using HttpClient i get no issues. curl also works without any issues. Why is the above golang code giving error ?

Since the target closes the connection with RST the reason likely lies within the target  - only nothing is known about it.  What can be seen though is that the TLS handshake is probably successful and the inner HTTP request send. This suggests that there is some logic denying specific clients, which is common for CDN and other solutions which try to detect and ban bots. I recommend you check if the site in question is behind some common CDN like Cloudflare, Akamai, Fastly, ..

Why is the sniffer data showing duplicate ACKs?  I would try Ping to see if you are making a good connection.  You may be going through a proxy and the proxy is the issue.  A connection will automatically close when an ACK is not seen after 3 attempts.
